# Two dependent request and recyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, coroutine

I have two requests that depend on each other and I want to pass both results to the recyclerView adapter.
Unfortunately, following code does not return data_1 in collect. But when I commented out second collect with data_2 then I see result for data_1.

```
class MyViewModel(UUID: GUID): ViewModel() { 

    private val _data_1: MutableStateFlow<List<Example>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    val data_1: StateFlow<List<Example>> get() = _data_1.asStateFlow()
    
    private val _data_2: MutableStateFlow<List<Example_2>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    val data_2: StateFlow<List<Example_2>> get() = _data_2.asStateFlow()

    init { 
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _repository.getData(UUID).collect { data_1 ->
            _data_1.value = data_1
            getSecondData(data_1)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getSecondData(item: List<Example>) {
        val list = mutableListOf<Event>()
            coroutineScope {
                for (item in items) {
                    async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        _repository.getSecondData(item).collect { it ->
                            list.add(it)
                        }
                    }.await()
                }
                _data_2.value = list
            }
    }
}
```

```
Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                myViewModel.data_1.collect { data_1 ->
                    myViewModel.data_2.collect { data_2 ->
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            binding.myRecyclerView.adapter = MyListAdapter(data_1, data_2)                  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have check with Log.d that data_1 with data_2 returns records. I have tried storing data_1 in private variable in fragment before calling second collect. I have tried joinAll option but together with launch/collect it will never work.
Why is it not working and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Mnemonic - what does the code in your repository look like?

Comment: Hi @karllindmark, I have Flow<List<Data>> = flow as return declaration and use emit method to inform that data has been received.

Comment: It looks that at the beginning I have emptyList for both, and later only second method update data, so I will have records in data_2 but data_1 still stay like it was. Without emit received records. One cancels the other? I don't understand.